# How to get the selected date in Calendar Picker on react native?

Tags: react-native

am using react-native-calendar-picker library.trying to get the selected date but i receive previews date.

```
 onDateChange (date) {
    this.setState({ date: date });        
}

<CalendarPicker selectedDate={this.state.date}
                        onDateChange=(date)=>this.onDateChange(date)}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use react-native-calendar

You can get it from here : https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-calendar

Usage Example :

```js
<Calendar
      scrollEnabled={true}
      showControls={true}
      titleFormat={'MMMM YYYY'}
      dayHeadings={['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu','Fri','Sat']}
      monthNames={['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']}
      prevButtonText={'Prev'}
      nextButtonText={'Next'}
      onDateSelect={(date) => this.onDateChange(date)}
      onTouchPrev={this.onTouchPrev}
      onTouchNext={this.onTouchNext}
      onSwipePrev={this.onSwipePrev}
      onSwipeNext={this.onSwipeNext}
      eventDates={this.state.events}
      customStyle={{day: {fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'center', color: '#4c4b4b'}}}
      weekStart={1}
      />
```